# Metaphor sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am having problem understanding a first sentence in second paragraph. I can understand it superficially but it is a metaphor and I cannot figure out what it the really means. I appreciate your help in advance.

> "Lum closes his volume with a poem that further points to the complex
>   relationships between heritage and local culture in determining one’s
>   identity. Pulling together images and figures as vastly disparate as a
>   famous Chinese American literary character and an old woman selling
>   bread,Lum avoids an excessively romantic vision of U.S.culture, while
>   simultaneously acknowledging the dream of this culture held by many
>   newly arrived immigrants.
>
> **The central image of a communal pot where each person chooses what
>   she or he wishes to eat but shares with others the “sweet soup /
>   spooned out at the end of the meal”is a hopeful one;** however,it also
>   appears to caution that the strong cultural emphasis in the U.S.on
>   individual drive and success that makes retaining a sense of homeland
>   tradition difficult should be identified and responded to in ways that
>   allow for a healthy new sense of identity to be formed."

Answer (score 1):

First, to be clear, the section in quotes is from a poem by Wing Tek Lum, Chinese Hot Pot.

I think the meaning the author is trying to convey is given in the last sentence - each can assert their own individuality, but the "sweet soup" was created only by everyone coming together as a community and preparing the meal in a single pot. While it may not be the only interpretation, the author interprets the poem as a warning about losing a sense of tradition.

The '/' in the middle of the sentence indicates a line break in the quoted poem.

Answer (score 0):

The context in which the sentence is built is the very vast that the U.S is a country of diversity. With different groups, community, race, etc.

The communal pot here signifies that everyone has where he "belongs" - a community, race, cultural affiliation which he chooses to identify himself (he eats from that pot)...

But at the end of the day, he shares on thing in common with others - the fact that he's in the U.S, he's a citizen, he's regarded a part of the U.S society. That's why many people go to the U.S - everyone feels good to identify with U.S(the identification would ultimately be "sweet")...

PS: I'm using "he" as a generic term

Comment: Thanks! Could you also explain why there is / in the middle of the sentence?

Comment: Its a kind of 'shorthand' way of indicating the words "and" or "or" without using the words themselves. Its is mostly used in informal writing, however.

Comment: The phrase “sweet soup / spooned out at the end of the meal” is quoted from a poem; the slash marks the end of a line of the poem.  https://wilkersonessayist.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/explication-3-for-engl-4669/